# How to change the cursor color to be seen against grey background in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, cursor

I'm wanting to change the cursor color because, I want to change the page background, and when I do that, the cursor seems to blend into the background.

What I did to find a solution:

I did change the color of the cursor via the ***Control panel*** to invert, and after to be black, and neither setting made it possible to see it against the background

Here's a picture of the regular page background with the cursor visible

[image: Regular page background with the cursor visible]

Cursor invisible in Microsoft Word after changing the cursor settings via the Control Panel, against the background changed to grey

[image: Cursor invisible against grey background]

Comment: If the cursor is the only issue, why don't you just keep the background white or a lighter shade of gray until you're finished?

Comment: Sometimes I'm writing something in low light conditions, and the white is a little bit straining on the eyes.